# jQuery not hiding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code, what I'm trying to do is have javascript check a form and then submit it to a PHP script via AJAX that will log the user in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RPEMS: Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css"></link>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javacript'>

$(function()
{
    $('.error').hide();
$('.button').click(function()
{
    $('.error').hide();
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var pass = $('input#pass').val();
    var err = false;

    if (!email)
    {
        $('label#emErr').show();
        $('input#email').focus();
        err = true;
    }

    if (!filter.test(email))
    {
        $('label#emValErr').show();
        $('input#email').focus();
        err = true;
    }

    if (!pass)
    {
        $('label#passErr').show();
        $('input#pass').focus();
        err = true;
    }

    if (err) return false;

    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "log.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(result)
    {
        if (result.success == true) window.location('../');
        else $('p#phpErr).html(result.message).show();
    }});
}
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png"></img>
            <ul id="navBar">
                <li class="navLink">
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navLink">
                    <a href="/about">About/Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navLink">
                    <a href="/calendar">Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navLink">
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <form method='post' action=''>
        <fieldset>
            <label for='email'>Email: </label>
            <input name='email' id='email' type='text'></input>
            <br class='error'></br>
            <label for='email' class='error' id='emErr'>This field is required</label>
            <label for='email' class='error' id='emValErr'>Invalid email adress</label>
            <br class='error'></br>

            <label for='pass'>Password: </label>
            <input name='pass' id='pass' type='password'></input>
            <br></br>
            <label for='pass' class='error' id='passErr'>This field is required</label>
            <br class='error'></br>
            <p class='error' id='phpErr'></p>

            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit_btn' value='Submit'></input>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Sadly when I load the page though, the errors aren't hidden, any idea why?

Comment: Does anything appear in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Is it legal to use `<br></br>` ?

Comment: @caligula in `application/xhtml+xml` it is. in plain old `text/html` it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in your code.   Please make sure you are always checking your console in the browser.  See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Dje/)

Here is your working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Dje/3/).   You are missing a single quote in your line `else $('p#phpErr').html(result.message).show();` as well as a closing `);` before your document.ready

Please always check your console as this will help you out with errors like this... If you dont know how to use the console.  [Check this out](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/google-chrome-dev-tools-how-to-use-the-console-panel/1195)

Comment: Seriously, the number of posters who apparently don't check the console before they wonder what's up. I can never get my head round it.

Answer (score -1):

you have illegal `MIME-type` for your script (missing `s`)

```
 <script type='text/javacript'>
```

That is why browser even does not attempt to execute it

Change to correct `type="text/javascript"`

Also at last lines of your script there is several syntax errors, fix to this:

```
            else $('p#phpErr').html(result.message).show(); //missing quote here
        }});
    }); //missing ) here
});
```